# Autofac Generic Service resolution at runtime

Tags: c#, autofac

Recently, Castle added support for interface factories with implementations provided by the kernel. I am wondering if there is a way to do this in autofac also. I have read about the delegate factories, but I think I might be missing something, and am unable to get it to work. Here is what I am thinking:

```cs
class Message { }

interface IHandle<T> {
    void Handle(T message);
}

class Handle<Message> : IHandle<Message> {
    ...
}

class Bus {
    .ctor (? lookup) {
        _lookup = lookup;
    }

    void Send<T>(T message) {
        _lookup.GetHandler<T>().Handle(message);
    }
}

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Handle<Message>>().As<IHandle<Message>>();
builder.RegisterType<Bus>();

var container = builder.Build();
container.Resolve<Bus>().Send<Message>(new Message());
```

What I'm trying to do is keep the container out of the bus (as I agree that service locator is an anti-pattern) or any other implementation. This problem is easy if I just feed the container to the bus, or create some class factory that wraps the container. Just trying to make sure there isn't a way to do this already.

Btw, the castle way iirc allows me to register something like this:

```cs
interface IHandlerFactory {
    IHandle<T> GetHandler<T>();
}

container.Register<IHandlerFactory>().AsFactory();
```

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: The Castle approach looks very clever - Autofac doesn't support this. I'm of the opinion that @kcalvanti's approach below is best for this scenario, however you can also use Autofac's `IIndex<K,V>` type to similar effect, with a little more configuration.

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt Yep, I'm going to accept his answer for now. If it changes in the future, I can definitely revisit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could isolate that coupling by creating a concrete `IHandlerFactory`, say `AutofacHandlerFactory`, which would receive the `ILifetimeScope`. That coupling seems inevitable since the container is the only one who can resolve the proper `IHandler<T>`.

Coupling with `ILifetimeScope` might be a bad idea, but then, the coupling is isolated inside the concrete `IHandlerFactory`, and the `Bus` just uses it through an interface. Let's say you change the container and starts using Ninject, you could just implement a `NinjectHandlerFactory` to do the job.

Comment: If the functionality doesn't exist to duplicate the Castle feature, this would definitely be the way to go (and is in fact how I have it now).

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the answer is 'No'.

I've tried to use [AggregateService](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/AggregateService) which is supposed to do what you want, but it crashes during factory resolution with message 'The type "Castle.Proxies.IComponentFactoryProxy" from assembly "DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" has tried to implement an unaccessible interface.' (The original message is in Russian, I've translated it).

I can't figure out another approach that would work without a manual (yet quite simple) implementation. Maybe you should write to Nicholas Blumhardt.

In fact, I'd better do it this way:

```
public class Bus {
  readonly ILifetimeScope _OwnScope;

  // Autofac always provides ILifetimeScope that owns a component as a service to the component
  // so it can be used as a dependency
  public Bus(ILifetimeScope ownScope) {
    _OwnScope = ownScope;
  }

  void Send<T>(T message) {
    _OwnScope.Resolve<IHandler<T>>.Handle(message);
  }
}
```

You will probably argue that coupling with `ILifetimeScope` is a bad idea. Well, it's quite a simple interface which might be wrapped into your own implementation. Or you may factor the code out into a simple factory class. Well, it seems like you know how to do this without my suggestions.

Comment: I have seen info about the aggregateservice before, but glanced over it. I think that might definitely be the way to go. I would agree, ILifetimeScope is a bad idea as that leaks autofac into my projects where it shouldn't be. A IHandlerFactory with autofacimpl would be the way I would go without getting too leaky.

Comment: @neouser99 Yeah, I just wish it worked. If you manage to make it work, please post some hints on the setup. Maybe I used some wrong Castle assemblies or whatever.