# How to inject a factory of generic types with Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a repository factory `NhRepositoryFactory`

```
public interface IRepositoryFactory  
{  
  IRepository<T> Create<T>() where T: Entity;  
} 

public class NhRepositoryFactory: IRepositoryFactory  
{  
  public IRepository<T> Create<T>() where T : Entity  
  {  
    return new NhRepository<T>();  
  }  
}
```

In order to resolve some repositories dependencies I want to get them from the Autofac container. So I should somehow inject `Func<IRepository<T>>` factory into my class. How can I accomplish this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why won't you store the Autofac container inside the `NhRepositoryFactory`?

Comment: I want my factory be Autofac-agnostic.

Comment: It contains just one single line of code. You can place it inside your composition root. It doesn't have to be container-agnostic.

Comment: I haven't got the point. `IRepositoryFactory` is also resolved with Autofac. Could you write what the `Create` method will look like?

Comment: Your question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579128/autofac-generic-service-resolution-at-runtime/8597212#8597212, so is the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `NhRepositoryFactory` contains no business logic and can be part of your composition root. This allows you to let it have a reference to the container. [This is just mechanics](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorRolesVsMechanics.aspx) and is not considered to be the Service Locator anti-pattern. The  `NhRepositoryFactory` will look like this:

```
// This class is part of your composition root
public class NhRepositoryFactory : IRepositoryFactory  
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public NhRepositoryFactory(Container container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public IRepository<T> Create<T>() where T : Entity  
    {  
        return this.container.Resolve<NhRepository<T>>();
    }  
}
```

And you can register it like this:

```
builder.Register<IService>(c => new NhRepositoryFactory(c))
    .SingleInstance();
```

Comment: I agree it seems inevitable to couple with Autofac one way or another. I've done it the way you suggested. The difference is that I passed `ILifetimeScope` instead of `Container`.

Comment: I've changed the implementation. I've created `IObjectFactory` interface with `T Create<T>()` method that uses `ILifetimeScope` to create objects. It is implemented by `AutofacObjectFactory` class which is injected into `NhRepositoryFactory`. So now there is no Autofac-coupling.

Comment: After the refactoring `IRepositoryFactory` has been eliminated. Its place has taken `IObjectFactory`.

Comment: I think this is just bad practice. Why are you returning NhRepository from factory as oppossed to feeding it in through constructor injection? Factory pattern makes no sense here.

Comment: @DmitriyMelnik May I ask the final example?

Answer (score 5):

Autofac is also able to handle the generic creation natively without the factory.

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(NhRepository<>))
    .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Using this pattern you can simply take a dependency on IRepository and autofac will fill out the dependencies.

Comment: I've tried it this way. But when some class needed several repositories I had to add them as constructor parameters. A field for each of them was to be created also. It seemed clumsy so I created a factory.